# Regex help to extract value from string

Tags: c#, regex

I can't figure out how to extract specific numbers with a specific match from a string.

Example:

```
string myString = "blah blah **[10]** blah **[20]** and some more blah **[30]**";
Regex myIDsReg = new Regex(@"\*\*\[(\d+)\]\*\*");
```

Apparently the regex is sound.

```
Match myMatch = myIDsReg.Match(myString);
```

Yields "**[10]**" but nothing else.

I can't figure out how to get an array with the following values: 10, 20, 30

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this

```
string myString = "blah blah **[10]** blah **[20]** and some more blah **[30]**";
Regex myIDsReg = new Regex(@"\*\*\[(\d+)\]\*\*");
string[] regexResult = (from Match match in myIDsReg.Matches(myString) select match.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

You can select which output you want as well

```
List<string> regexResult = (from Match match in myIDsReg.Matches(myString) select match.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
```

or

```
IEnumerable<string> regexResult = (from Match match in myIDsReg.Matches(myString) select match.Groups[1].Value);
```

I'd prefer one of the two latter

Comment: I had to modify it a little to work the way I need it to work.  But this was the best answer for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx) instead of `Match`.

```
foreach (Match match in myIDsReg.Matches(myString))
{
    // etc...
}
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/xyo6u)

Answer (score 1):

Trikks came up with the best answer.  I just had to modify it a little to work best for me.

```
string myString = "blah blah **[10]** blah **[20]** and some more blah **[30]**";
Regex myIDsReg = new Regex(@"\*\*\[(\d+)\]\*\*");
string[] regexResult = (from Match match in myIDsReg.Matches(myString) select match.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

I basically replaced "select match.Value" with "select match.Groups[1].Value".

Thanks for your help!